# Reference Main Control from User Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I am using WPF to write an Application.

The Main window of the Application is called systemInfo.

In system Info I have a search user control and a tab control that has multiple tabs.

I have a System Entity that relates to every single one of the tabs. Using the System entity ID, the information is loaded into each tab after the Search control finds the entity.

My problem is, After the information is Loaded into the first tab, and another tab is clicked the "System Entity" and the "System Entity ID" disappear. Thus I am unable to load the information for that same Entity without searching again for the Entity.

I need a way to retain the "System Entity" and the "System Entity ID" information across all the tabs.

EDIT:
TO CLARIFY:
This is not an issue with the retrieval of the data. The Data is retrieved properly using a service that accesses the information in the SQL Server database.

The problem is in the XAML and the Forms that display the data. The first tab Loads initially with the information retrieved from the Database using the System Entity ID. The following tab loads based on that information. But when the Original Tab or any other tab is clicked. that ID is not retained it is lost and it can't retrieve the data because the ID does not exist.

I can't provide code because the code doesn't exist to handle this interaction. The Main Window is a container and all the other items (Tab content, Search Control) are User Controls.

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

thank you,

Sam

Comment: Posting some code would help.  Where are you storing your data behind the UI?  Is it just in the xaml.cs or are you using a ViewModel?

Comment: The data is stored in a SQL Server Database.

The interaction with the datastore is outside the scope of this question. I am trying to have the System Entity ID persist for the duration of interaction. 

I need to be able to pass the ID between the tabs in the code behind for each one of the xaml forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you storing your data? What codes are run when the tab is clicked (on the event).
I guess if you put some code over here that would help a lot to understand your problem.

Comment: The data is accessed using Services.

The problem is not with Data access. the problem is with retaining the current System Entity ID in the application. It has nothing to do with data retrieval or accessing the data.

I need to be Able to pass the ID within the Application Framework.